# In a city travel ticket booking mobile app, can 'expected travel time from A to B' be a crucial decision making piece of information for a user?

Tags: app, travel

I am working on the information architecture of the a city travel ticket that needs to be shown to the user in a list. I have stuff on it like 'From'; 'To'; 'Departure Time'. The 'Expected travel time' in not there at the moment and we are thinking over it. How much of an impact this feature will make on users decision of purchasing a particular route over other. The average travel time of the user can vary from 15 minutes to 20 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider the goal of your user in this case. If you have any idea what your typical user is, you could figure this out by defining personas or talking to a few potential users.

I would expect that, when a user considers buying a ticket, the following applies:

- Is it going to be worth it, or is walking just as fast/efficient? Not knowing any expected travel time, means that it could be 15 minutes, 20 minutes, or maybe a few hours.
- whether he or she is going to be 'on time' at the place of arrival.

Any type of public transit app I know shows me exactly that. When I book a flight online or a bus, or a train, it will always show me what the expected travel time is, and often even a few minutes (especially for short trips such as a bus) could make a difference.

But again, I would say, in this case, get to know your user.